# Angular 2 Dynamic Forms - Can somebody explain the FormControl initialization

Tags: angular

Can somebody explain me the following code, specifically what do "group", "group[question.key]" imply? How is FormControl being initialized and what does assignment to group[] mean?
Do I need to provide [formControlName] to each control on the HTML page?

```
toGroup(){
        let group:any = {};
        this.questions.forEach((question) => {
            if(question.required){
                group[question.key] = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
            }
            else{
                group[question.key] = new FormControl('');
            }
        });
        return new FormGroup(group);
    }
```